# Facebook Login Issue with Cakephp Application

Tags: facebook, cakephp-2.3

I am trying login with fb on my cakephp application. Things as well as flow is working fine for first time. But in case if I am already autorised for that app or I am already logged in other tab with fb account my function retrieved 0.

Let me paste sample code here.

```
    public function facebookLogin() {
        App::import('Vendor', 'facebook/facebook');

        $fb = new Facebook(array('appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID, 'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET));
        $user = $fb->getUser();
        if (!$user && !isset($this->request->query['code'])) {
            $params = array(
                'scope' => 'email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown',
                'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
            );
            $loginUrl = $fb->getLoginUrl($params);
            $this->redirect($loginUrl);
        }
        echo "After Login  !!";
        $userProfile = $fb->api('/me');
        $accessToken = $fb->getAccessToken();

        debug($this->request->query);
        MY LOGIC TO SAVE N UPDATE HERE.
    }
```

Exact issue is for first time I am validating for permission to use app. Its returning me user profile with detail function '$fb->api('/me')' but in case if I am already authorized or I have logged in with fb in another tab. It returns 0 as $user. When I tried same function to retrieve '$fb->api('/me')' data it halt me with error **'An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.'**

I can't understand what get params it returns in my second go. My $_GET request retrieves code n state in second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you implement the login using the example as stated here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

You should use `getLoginUrl()` and `getSessionFromRedirect()` to determine if someone is logged in.